# CSS transition on SVG causes flickering IE11 and Edge

Tags: html, css, svg, css-transitions

I have a SVG image placed in my header. The image has a fixed width and when I scroll down I add a CSS class to my header to change the width of the image. It works fine except It flickers in IE11 and Edge, works fine in Chrome.

```
img {
  transition: width 5s ease; 
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/980754/

Comment: IE/Edge strikes again! Good news: it's a bug known to MS, basically it loads the SVG asynchronously, thus when you transition the size, it rerenders the SVG everytime, but misses a few frames (hence the flickering). Bad news: they won't fix it, cause it's Microsoft. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10440554/ Sadly I don't see a solution, other than not using SVG.

(Other related good news: MS will probably shut down Edge, so in 2 years we may not have to bother with that again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of transitionning the width, use [CSS Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform). Using `transform: scale(0.5);` and a transition targetting transform, you'll get what you're looking for without the need for a repaint and you'll get a much smoother animation.

Here is your updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kyawjn4s/1/

Comment: Hi Jake, works smooth! Problem now is that I would like to have two images beside each other, without the gap the scale causes, do you think that's possible?https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/981785/

Comment: Not really, but you can combine it with `translateX` to kinda fake it. https://jsfiddle.net/9knpvqro/

Comment: CSS transforms are only visual effects if one might say, they are out of the flow and do not affect block size. As elveti said, the only option would be to combine scale and translate to have them side by side.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `img` tag, give `object` a try. It even gives you a fallback option and resolves the flickeing issue on IE/Edge. It should work on older browsers too.

**Example**

```
<object data="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/adobe.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="200">
    <!--Fallback image for older browsers -->
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x200" />
</object>
```

I've updated you jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/axdetm4h/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to place the SVG inline. It works fine in Edge and IE 11.

**Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SVG inline</title>
<style>
svg{width:200px;transition:width .5s}
svg:hover{width:500px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your CSS to:

```
-webkit-transition: width 5s ease;
-moz-transition: width 5s ease;
-ms-transition: width 5s ease;
-o-transition: width 5s ease;
transition: width 5s ease;
```